# React-native compilation error: opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

```
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
```

```
library: 'digital envelope routines',

reason: 'unsupported',

code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
```

I update my node version and then I fetched this type of error.

Answer (score 7):

If you have updated your Node version to 17+, you need to upgrade your react-scripts too, to version 5 or above. See [here](https://github.com/horacehylee/pixely/pull/27).

You can do so by running `npm install react-scripts@latest`, as instructed in the [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/) site.

Comment: this answer targets a React app. OPs question is for react-native, which can be deduced from the type of error as well as the question's tags

Comment: Even though this error may also appear in React Native, I encountered it while working on my React webapp. I am actually working on a new React project (not React Native) and just now had the same exact error after running `npm start`: `opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ]`.

Comment: Interesting. Still, react-native projects don't use react-scripts.

Comment: not helpful for  react-native

Comment: The answer does not relates to the actual question, react-scripts is for web only, not for mobile

Answer (score 0):

```
create-react-library
```

If you are getting the following error:

```
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
Compiled successfully!
```

```
example folder -> package.json -> 
"start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start", 
"build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build", 
"test": "react-scripts test", 
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
```